# How can I know the path to the image in css? webpack and reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using `webpack` and `reactjs`

My folder code structure is like this.

```
src/components
src/css
src/images/myUiButtonImg.png
          /myUiButtonImg_hover.png
          /correct_img.png
```

There are some png files in `images` folder and `basic.style.module.css` is in  `css` folder.

I want to use the png as UI button in `component/pain.js`

```
import styles from "../css/basic-styles.module.css";
correct_img from "../images/correct_img.png";
....

<a href="/"><div className={styles.myUIButton}/></a> // try to get png from css.
<img src={{correct_img}}> // this shows correctly.
...
```

in `basic.style.module.css`

```
.myUIButton {
    width:20px;
    background:url("/src/images/myUiButtonImg.png");
}
.myUIButton:hover{
  background:url("/src/images/myUiButtonImg_hover.png");
}
```

In this case, `correct_img` shown properly but `myUiButtonImg` is not.

Is it possible to use the ping in css??

---

My webpack setting is like this below

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
   entry: "./src/index.js",
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
       filename: "[name].js",
   },

   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
               use: {
                   loader: "babel-loader",
                   options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
                  }
               },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            //[name]は画像名、[ext]は拡張子
                            name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
       ],
   },
   optimization: {
       minimize: true,
   },
   plugins: [
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('production')
       })
   ]
}
```

After compiling with this there all image files are copied here.

in `static/frontend/images/(every images here)`

So, I try this in css.

```
background-image: url("/static/frontend/images//src/images/myUiButtonImg_hover.png");
```

However when cheking this in chrome inspector.

This link is changed like this, and can not reach the file.

http://localhost:8021/static/frontend/beb274f7a2473271be12.png

Answer (score 0):

Is the basic.style.module.css in the root folder?

In the first example you go back into the src folder and navigate to the image.
In the second you start directly from the src folder. This might be the wrong path `src/components/src/images/myUiButtonImg.png`.

To test if the image can be displayed correctly you could try using the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these rules in your `webpack.config.js`. The second rule loads the files ending with `*.module.css` as css modules otherwise the `styles` import in your component will be `undefined`. The third rule loads all the `*.png` and other asset files.

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'style-loader' },
      { loader: 'css-loader' },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.module\.css$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'style-loader' },
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
]
```